# Show "Add to cart button" but don't allow to add to cart for "out of stock" products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce I am willing to show products that are out of stock but I don't want to sell them. I would like to have custom "ask for availability" button for it with contact form on the popup (any solution similar to that would be great)

I managed to change button title but how can I forbid to add product to the cart and show some contact form instead? I tried a lot of plugins for that but I coun't have find any suitable one.

Thanks for any answear!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Popup contact form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-contact-form/), which will allow you to have a popup contact form. In the settings of the plugin (found in the Settings tab on the dashboard) change the `Link Button / Text` to "Ask for availability".

Copy the `abstract-wc-product.php` file (found in: `woocommrece/includes/abstracts/`) to  `yourtheme/woocommrece/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php` add `PopupContact();` to line ~613 (where it has/had the text "Out of stock").

When a product is out of stock it should show the "Ask for availability" text and clicking on that text should show the form pop up.